# deriving a class from another class causes Com registration error

Tags: c#, wpf, class, inheritance

I have a project that follows WPF/MVVM pattern. I have tried to derive my ViewModel class from PropertyChangedBase so that I can Notify of data changes to the view. As soon as I derive the class from PropertyChangeBase and compile, I get error saying

**Error 1   Cannot register assembly "D:\Source\ArcOnline\bin\Debug\ArcOnline.dll". Could not load file or assembly 'Major, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

here is how my class is defined

```
using ArcOnline.WPF;
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace ArcOnline.ViewModels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The class handles the template for a single 
    /// </summary>
    public class TemplatesViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public ArcOnlineViewModel ArcManager { get; set; }

        private string _layerID;
        /// <summary>
        /// Layer ID
        /// </summary>
        public string LayerID
        {
            get { return _layerID; }
            set { _layerID = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LayerID); }
        }

        private string _title;
        /// <summary>
        /// Title of the layer
        /// </summary>
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Title); }
        }
```

............. More properties as above
    }

and here is the how my PropertyChangedBase is defined

```
using Component.Linq.Expressions;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
#endregion

namespace Component.ComponentModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A base class from which ViewModels can inherit to improve the quality of
    /// patterns such as INotifyPropertyChanged.
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PropertyChangedBase"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public PropertyChangedBase()
        {
            ErrorsChanged += Notify_ErrorChanged;
        }

        void Notify_ErrorChanged(object sender, DataErrorsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Error);
        }

 ...... More class definition continues

}
```

This PropertyChangedBase is actually defined in a different Project so that is why it has all the header files included. If I copy the code of this PropertyChangedBase class and create a new class in my own Project where TemplatesViewModel is defined and then use it, it works perfectly fine.

I just want to know what is the reason for it not working in the first case?? This wasted my whole day!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I can remember, you can't have a `Serializable` class that also contains the `INotifyOfPropertyChanged` interface. Try removing one or the other and try to rebuild... if it builds, then that's your problem.

Comment: Header files?  COM registration??  What on Earth are you doing?  Ensure that the "Register for COM interop" option is turned off.